# Shared prototype beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need to create multiple instances of a spring bean (let's call it `MainPrototypeBean`), which I can do with the `prototype` scope. It depends on some other beans, and I want to create new instances of them each time the main bean is created. However, there is a shared dependency between some of the beans, let's call it `SharedPrototypeBean`. How do I inject the same instance of `SharedPrototypeBean` in each of the dependent beans, while also creating a new instance for each `MainPrototypeBean`?

I'm looking into implementing a custom scope, but I'm hoping to find a cleaner way. Making any of the beans singletons is not an option, as they need to be isolated between different instances of `MainPrototypeBean`.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DIDemo {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DIDemo.class, args);
        context.getBean(MainPrototypeBean.class);
    }

    @Component @Scope("prototype") static class SharedPrototypeBean {}

    @Component @Scope("prototype") static class FirstPrototypeBean {
        @Autowired SharedPrototypeBean shared;
        @PostConstruct public void init() {
            System.out.println("FirstPrototypeBean.init() with shared " + shared);
        }
    }

    @Component @Scope("prototype") static class SecondPrototypeBean {
        @Autowired SharedPrototypeBean shared;
        @PostConstruct public void init() {
            System.out.println("SecondPrototypeBean.init() with shared " + shared);
        }
    }

    @Component @Scope("prototype") static class MainPrototypeBean {
        @Autowired FirstPrototypeBean first;
        @Autowired SecondPrototypeBean second;
    }
}
```

And the output of executing it is:

```
FirstPrototypeBean.init() with shared DIDemo$SharedPrototypeBean@1b84f475
SecondPrototypeBean.init() with shared DIDemo$SharedPrototypeBean@539d019
```

Comment: Prototype beans have different instance for each injection that container makes. I would argue that `SharedPrototypeBean` is in fact not a prototype-scoped bean, but a `@Scope("singleton")`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov but wouldn't that mean the same `SharedPrototypeBean` would be used for all `MainPrototypeBean` instances, thus defiling the requisite?

Comment: Note: I suspect using a scope proxy might help here.

Comment: @Mena, it would, sort of. But then, why specifically have distinct 
`SecondPrototypeBean` dependency on main bean at all? It would be cleaner to define separate bean classes for shared dependency and for non-shared dependency.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov that makes sense to me. Just trying to think how the OP's requirements are feasible :)

Comment: @Mena, proxied scopes are even trickier. Proxied prototype beans may go as far as to create a separate instances on each and every method call. As far as I understand, there isn't really a step in-between singleton scope and prototype scope there, without using a custom scope. However, scopes are not aware of the purpose that bean creation is requested, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Mena, honestly, this requirement sounds to me like that `SecondPrototypeBean` is a type of bean that has too many responsibilities inside it, where it's pretty safe to split those in half and make one half singleton and the other half prototype-scoped.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov but this is not only about `SecondPrototypeBean`: both `First` and `SecondPrototypeBean` share the `SharedPrototypeBean` dependency, which the OP wants to be the same instance. So, `First` and `Second` are prototypes to `Main`, which is also a prototype. The tricky part is to have `Shared` deliver the same instance to `First` and `Second` when injected.

Comment: @Mena, if `Shared` is singleton, it will deliver the same instance. Point is I don't think it's really feasible to have two separate bean types or at least configurations for each purpose.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov fair enough, you know more than I do. I just think if `Shared` is singleton, then it will the same instance singleton for all instances of `First` and `Second`, which is not what the OP seems to want.

Comment: @Mena, there is always also a manual configuration option. His bean could define a method which parent class will call, like a setter for shared dependency. His post construct won't work either way though, because bean is constructed first, and only then injected somewhere. Or maybe his `Second` and `First` are not component beans at all, and should just be normally constructed rather than injected by container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments and the other answer, I realized that the design is indeed too complex. I made `SharedPrototypeBean`, `FirstPrototypeBean` and `SecondPrototypeBean` regular POJOs, not managed by Spring. I then create all of the objects in a `@Bean` annotated method.

```
@Bean
public MainPrototypeBean mainPrototypeBean() {
    Shared shared = new Shared();
    First first = new First(shared);
    Second second = new Second(shared);
    return new MainPrototypeBean(first, second);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FactoryBean` for complex construction logic. Implement its abstract subclass `AbstractFactoryBean` for creating a `MainPrototypeBean`,  and inject all three dependent beans into it. You can then wire them together in the `createInstance` method.

The FactoryBean implementation:

```
public class MainFactoryBean extends AbstractFactoryBean<MainPrototypeBean> implements FactoryBean<MainPrototypeBean> {

private FirstPrototypeBean firstPrototype;
private SecondPrototypeBean secondPrototpye;
private SharedPrototypeBean sharedPrototype;

public MainFactoryBean(FirstPrototypeBean firstPrototype, SecondPrototypeBean secondPrototype, SharedPrototypeBean sharedPrototype) {
    this.firstPrototype = firstPrototype;
    this.secondPrototpye = secondPrototype;
    this.sharedPrototype = sharedPrototype;
}


@Override
protected MainPrototypeBean createInstance() throws Exception {
    MainPrototypeBean mainPrototype = new MainPrototypeBean();
    firstPrototype.setSharedPrototypeBean(sharedPrototype);
    secondPrototpye.setSharedPrototypeBean(sharedPrototype);
    mainPrototype.first = firstPrototype;
    mainPrototype.second = secondPrototpye;

    //call post construct methods on first and second prototype beans manually 
    firstPrototype.init();
    secondPrototpye.init();
    return mainPrototype;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return MainPrototypeBean.class;
}
}
```

*Note*: `sharedPrototype` is injected after the post-construct phase in the lifecycle of the first and second prototype. So, if you have post-construction logic in these beans that require the `sharedPrototype`, you need to manually call the init-method when creating the `MainPrototypeBean`.

Your annotation - configuration changes as as a consequence. The `sharedPrototype` attributes are no longer autowired (they are set inside FactoryBean), and `MainPrototypeBean` is not annotated anymore. Instead you need to create the `MainFactoryBean`.

```
@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

//method name is the name refers to MainPrototypeBean, not to the factory
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public MainFactoryBean mainPrototypeBean(FirstPrototypeBean firstPrototype, SecondPrototypeBean secondPrototype, SharedPrototypeBean sharedPrototype) {
    return new MainFactoryBean(firstPrototype, secondPrototype, sharedPrototype);
}
//Annotations are not needed anymore
static class MainPrototypeBean {
    FirstPrototypeBean first;
    SecondPrototypeBean second;
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
static class SharedPrototypeBean {
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
static class FirstPrototypeBean {
    private SharedPrototypeBean shared;
    //no autowiring required
    public void setSharedPrototypeBean(SharedPrototypeBean shared) {
        this.shared = shared;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {//reference to shared will be null in post construction phase
        System.out.println("FirstPrototypeBean.init() with shared " + shared);
    }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
static class SecondPrototypeBean {

    private SharedPrototypeBean shared;
    public void setSharedPrototypeBean(SharedPrototypeBean shared) {
        this.shared = shared;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("SecondPrototypeBean.init() with shared " + shared);
    }
}
}
```